# Taxonomy.php inheriting first post

Tags: taxonomy, terms, archives

I created a generic taxonomy.php file to list posts with certain terms.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php 
if ( have_posts() ) : 
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><h1><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h1></a>
    <?php endwhile; 
endif; 
?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

The page works fine but it looks like it's inheriting terms and other things from the first post of the list in the loop... it even has the post ID of that said post.

How do I prevent this from happening? I have conditions within my enqueue.php that loads different styles for this particular post which I don't want.

Comment: Are you using `query_posts` anywhere in your code?

Comment: @TomJNowell inside taxonomy.php? What you see in the code snippet is all I have in that file.

Comment: Anywhere in your code, be it a plugin, `functions.php`, `query_posts` is insidious and its impact isn't isolated to the file it's called in. Can you update your queston to be clearer/clarify better what you meant? It's difficult to picture what your asking about. Give examples, including the actual taxonomy being used, the URLs, etc. There's an edit link under the list of tags you can use to make the adjustments.